# Toggle an input html between select option and input.text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have case like this.
I have a modal bootstrap that contains a html's form. With this modal, user can create a new data or just edit the data that has exist.
This is the html :

```
<button type="button" id="add_eir" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-flat bg-navy-active"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>   Add</button>

<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btnEdit' value='$row->REPAIR_ESTIMATE_ID'>Edit</button>
```

This is the bootstrap modal when user add a new data :

```
<div class="modal fade fullscreen " id="modal_form" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">No Inspeksi : </h4>
        </div>

        <?php echo form_open('', array('id' => 'upload_eir', 'class' => "form-horizontal")); ?>
        <div class="modal-body form">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="no_inspection" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label">Nomor</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                            <select data-placeholder="Pilih no inpeksi..." class="form-control chosen-select" name="no_inspection" id="no_inspection" style="width:250px;" tabindex="2">
                                <option></option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($all_inspection_belum_eor as $row) :
                                    echo "<option value='$row->NO_INSPECTION'> $row->NO_SURAT ( $row->PREFIX - $row->SERIAL_NUMBER ) </option>";
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comments" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hasil Survey</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="14" placeholder="Hasil Survey" name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>


    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Please see in modal body, there is have a select option. Now, How can I change this select option to common input text in edit action ?

So, when user choose to edit, select option will be change to input text, but still in same id, which is `no_inspection` ? Any help, it so appreciatd..

Comment: In edit time `$all_inspection_belum_eor` is blank or not

Comment: Please Give a jsfiddle to Help you Brother

Comment: You can try `.replaceWith()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a hidden div that contains textbox with values in the same div  and when user click on edit , you can hide the select box and show the text box with values with the help of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add or remove the two elements depending on what you select same ID may cause prob. in two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute to div after label as below:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="no_inspection" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label">Nomor</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10" id="detachit">
                        <select data-placeholder="Pilih no inpeksi..." class="form-control chosen-select" name="no_inspection" id="no_inspection" style="width:250px;" tabindex="2">
                            <option></option>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($all_inspection_belum_eor as $row) :
                                echo "<option value='$row->NO_INSPECTION'> $row->NO_SURAT ( $row->PREFIX - $row->SERIAL_NUMBER ) </option>";
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Then add an id to your Edit button (ex: id="add_eir").

Then use the below Jquery function:

```
$(function(){
   $("#add_eir").on('click',function(){
      $("#detachit").html("");
      $("#detachit").append('<input type="text" id="no_inspection" />');
   });
});
```